# Changing position of elements with css position: absolute

Tags: javascript, css

I have 6 button elements, with the css position: absolute, and I'm trying to position them using the css "left" style. Why does this code not work? They all just stay stacked in the top left corner. I'm assuming that it's to do with my javascript.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].style.left = "'" + String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 600)) + "px'";
}
```

```css
.game button {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="game" id="divi">
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

If you know of a way to have the buttons not interact with eachother at all, without position: absolute, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the extra quotes:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].style.left = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 600)) + "px";
}
```

```css
.game button {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="game" id="divi">
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
<button class="game"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

With this CSS, all these buttons will overwrite each other, located on the top-left of the screen.
Try this:

```
.game button {
  left: 10px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I just saw that you're new here. The help section has a section about how to write a good answer. What you have posted does not answer the question, nor will it work. For additional info, downvoting a question is free,  but downvoting an answer costs the voter a reputation point. It's not random trolling.